# Making my Clojure map function implementation faster

Tags: performance, clojure, functional-programming

I've been experimenting with Clojure lately. I tried writing my own map function (two actually) and timed them against the built in function. However, my map functions are way way slower than the built in one. I wanted to know how I could make my implementation faster. It should give me some insights into performance tuning Clojure algorithms I write. The first function **(my-map)** does recursion with recur. The second version **(my-map-loop)** uses loop/recur which was much faster than simply using recur.

```
(defn my-map
    ([func lst] (my-map func lst []))
    ([func lst acc]
        (if (empty? lst)
            acc
            (recur func (rest lst) (conj acc (func (first lst)))))))

(defn my-map-loop
    ([func lst]
        (loop [acc []
                     inner-lst lst]
            (if (empty? inner-lst)
                acc
                (recur (conj acc (func (first inner-lst))) (rest inner-lst))
                ))))

(let [rng (range 1 10000)]
    (time (map #(* % %) rng))
    (time (my-map #(* % %) rng))
    (time (my-map-loop #(* % %) rng)))
```

These are the results I got -

```
"Elapsed time: 0.084496 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 14.132217 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 7.324682 mess"
```

**Update**

After resueman pointed out that I was timing things incorrectly, I changed the functions to:

```
(let [rng (range 1 10000)]
  (time (doall (map #(* % %) rng)))
  (time (doall (my-map #(* % %) rng)))
  (time (doall (my-map-loop #(* % %) rng)))
  nil)
```

These are the new results:

```
"Elapsed time: 9.563343 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 12.320779 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 5.608647 mess"

"Elapsed time: 11.103316 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 18.307635 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 5.86644 mess"

"Elapsed time: 10.276658 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 10.288517 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 6.19183 mess"

"Elapsed time: 9.277224 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 13.070076 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 6.830464 mess"
```

Looks like my second implementation is fastest of the bunch. Anyways, I would still like to know if there are ways to optimize it further.

Comment: Beware using `time` to benchmark on the JVM.  JIT warmup can have a significant impact on results.  `time` can provide a first-order approximation, but it's best to use a proper benchmarking framework like Criterium (linked to in one of the answers) if you really care about accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could be leveraged to have a faster map: transients (for your accumulator), chunked seqs (for the source but only make sense when you want a lazy output), reducible collections (for the source again) and getting more familiar with the core functions (there's is a mapv).

You should also consider using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) instead of `time` if only for the fact that it checks whether your JVM optimizations are capped (which is the default with `lein`).

```
=> (let [rng (range 1 10000)]
       (quick-bench (my-map-loop #(* % %) rng))
       (quick-bench (into [] (map #(* % %)) rng)) ; leveraging reducible collections and transients 
       (quick-bench (mapv #(* % %) rng))) ; existing core fn

(output elided to keep only the means)
             Execution time mean : 776,364755 µs
             Execution time mean : 409,737852 µs
             Execution time mean : 456,071295 µs
```

It is interesting to note that `mapv` is no faster than `(into [] (map #(* % %)) rng)` that is a generic way of optimizing these kinds of computations.

Comment: I don't get the replacement of `#(* % %)` with just `*`. You're not removing indirections, you're removing multiplications! `(* x)` is just `x`, for any `x`.

Comment: @amalloy thanks for spotting this glaring oversight. I edited my reply accordingly.